# kafka broker server uneven CPU utilization

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, monitoring, cpu-usage

We have 3 node of kafka cluster with around 32 topic and 400+ partition
spread across these servers. We have the load evenly distributed amongst
this partition however we are observing that 2 broker server are running
around >60% CPU where as the third one is running just abour 10%. How do we
ensure that all server are running smoothly? Do i need to reassing the
partition (kafka-reassign-parition cmd).

PS: The partition are evenly distributed across all the broker servers.
[image: Uneven CPU utilization graph]

Comment: Are all three servers functioning as brokers? or is one of them a zookeeper. Can you seen that messages are being consumed/produced equally for all nodes?

Comment: What services are running on each server?

Comment: all are running zookeper and kafka services only.

Comment: PFA the total number of message received for each broker server along with CPU utlization for the server for that day.https://ibb.co/bR4HF3m
https://ibb.co/yPPKVtr

Comment: I suggest getting JMX montitoring on both ZK and Kafka

Comment: We are already monitoring it using datadog. Do you suggest some specific metrics to be measured?

Comment: Hey @ParthGandhi, we are seeing a similar trend on our brokers. Were you able to find the cause behind this?

Comment: @ParthGandhi – We are also experiencing something similar. Any updates on this post?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, this is a result of the way that individual consumer groups determine which partition to use within the `__consumer_offsets` topic.

On a high level, each consumer group updates only one partition within this topic. This often results in a `__consumer_offsets` topic with a highly uneven distribution of message rates.

It may be the case that:
You have a couple very heavy consumer groups, meaning they need to update the `__consumer_offsets` topic frequently. One of these groups uses a partition that has the 2nd broker as its leader. The other uses a partition that has the 3rd broker as its leader.
This would result in a significant amount of the CPU being utilized for updating this topic, and would only occur on the 2nd and 3rd brokers (as seen in your screenshot).

A detailed blog post is [found here](https://community.zuora.com/t5/Engineering-Blog/How-We-Triaged-Uneven-CPU-Load-in-our-Kafka-Cluster/ba-p/22016)